# Javascript number of object by different property values in array

Tags: javascript

Best way to count the number of objects in a array with different object property p values.

```
function([{"p":"a"},{"p":"b"},{"p":"a"}]){
    // some code
}
// in this case return 2
```

Comment: A clue: `.map().filter().length` or [`reduce()`](http://www.francisco.io/javascript-avoid-globals-with-reduce) <= (disclaimer, my blog post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)** to keep values that you want. In this case, you must create a variable `temp` for storing duplicate values and also within the `filter function` returns `true` if it does not exist in case. So you have a new array of **unique values**.

```js
var arr = [{"p":"a"},{"p":"b"},{"p":"a"}], temp = [];

var arrUniques = arr.filter(function(obj){
  return temp.indexOf(obj.p) === -1 ? !!temp.push(obj.p) : false
});

alert(arrUniques.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
var props = new Map();
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var prop = array[i].p,
        count = props.get(prop) || 0;

    props.set(prop, count + 1);
}

var size = props.size;
```

If your properties can be safely casted to strings, you can use a common object:

```
var props = {};
...
var size = Object.keys(props).length;
```

Otherwise, `Map` is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[lodash](http://lodash.com) is nice for things like this.

Use

```
_.uniq([{"p":"a"},{"p":"b"},{"p":"a"}]).length
```

and it'll return `2`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getUniquePropertyCount(a, p) {
    return a.reduce(function (res, el) {
        !~res.indexOf(el[p]) && res.push(el[p]);
        return res;
    }, []).length;
}
document.write(getUniquePropertyCount([{ "p": "a" }, { "p": "b" }, { "p": "a" }], 'p'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is one of those questions where if you ask four programmers, you'll get five answers.

The other answers so far show some interesting approaches. I would watch out for browser compatibility; for example `Map()` is only available in the newest browsers, not in IE 10 or prior.

So here's one more solution. It's a bit more code, but it's pretty easy to understand, and it works in every browser:

```
function countUniqueProperties( key, array ) {
    var count = 0, values = {};
    for( var i = 0;  i < array.length;  ++i ) {
        var value = array[i][key];
        if( ! Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( values, value) ) {
            ++count;
            values[value] = true;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

countUniqueProperties( 'p', [ {p:'a'}, {p:'b'}, {p:'a'} ] );
```

The one complicated part here is the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(values,value)`. You could just use `values.hasOwnProperty(value)`, but that would fail if one of your property values was the string `"hasOwnProperty"`:

```
countUniqueProperties( 'p', [ {p:'a'}, {p:'hasOwnProperty'}, {p:'a'} ] );
```

Using the longer form avoids this issue.